# problem with Python login recovery system

Tags: python, python-3.x

This Is a system where the user can recover their username or password

```
account = input("What do you want to recover? Username or Password? ")
if account == ("Password") or account == ("password"):
    check = True
    while check:
        username = input("Enter your username for your account ")
        with open("accountfile.txt","r") as file:
            for line in file:
                text = line.strip().split()
                if username in text:
                    print(line)
                    check = False
                else:
                    print("Username not found")
```

The format in the text file is: `username: (username) password: (password)` For some reason when I enter the username for the account it gives the password for it but for some reason it says at the end `Username not found` and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You need to exit from the for loop. It prints the username, then the next evaluation comes, and then the username is not there, so it prints Username not found. Isn't this the issue?

Comment: put in a "break" after check = False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `check = False`, you'll have to add `break`. This is because your loop keeps on going for every line, causing the "No Username Found" print. Also, since `check` becomes `False`, we can check this after the loop is done. The code would be:

```
account = input("What do you want to recover? Username or Password? ")
if account == ("Password") or account == ("password"):
    check = True
    while check:
        username = input("Enter your username for your account ")
        with open("accountfile.txt","r") as file:
            for line in file:
                text = line.strip().split()
                if username in text:
                    print(line)
                    check = False
                    break
            if (check == True):
                print("Username not found")
```

Results:
[image: Results]

Input:
[image: Input]

Comment: This is only a partial answer. The script will keep printing "Username not found" until it finds a match – that is, if the username is on line 42, you'll see 41 lines saying "Username not found".

Comment: @JJJ  Yep you were right I put other users into the file and tested it and it sthttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062441/problem-with-python-login-recovery-system/54063989#comment94963389_54063989ill sayes `username not found` do you know a permanent fix?

Comment: Check edit. Just fixed it. @python987 Also, added input and results.